# socket.emit() fails to send large data (30MB)

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I am using socket.emit() to transfer data from a server to some clients.
Sometimes the data I want to send reaches 30MB which I am sending for testing purposes to only 1 client. The data, which I am sending, is encoded within a JSON object. For smaller data the code works.

Therefor, transmitting the data fails with actually no error.

Node.js memory goes up to 1.5 GB and then after a while it says the client disconnected.
First of all, why does the memory go up to 1.5 GB when sending 30MB data?
Secondly, is this a browser issue or has it something to do with socket.io?
Or do I have a serious memory leak (the memory goes up when sending, not before)?
Other ideas and help are very appreciated :)
Thanks !

```
for (var x in candidates) { 
  candidates[x].emit('informUser', {
      action : action,
      test : test
   });
}
```

Action is just another Identifier within the custom event 'informUser'.
test contains the data (test object).